# How to make this if statement more elegant in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization

In my project, there is a logic similar to the following code, and there will be **many types**, but this is too messy to write, I want to ask if there is any more elegant way.

```
int a = 3,b = 5;
int type = 2;
if (type == 1) {
    if (a > 1) {
        System.out.println("a > 1");
    } else if (b > 3) {
        System.out.println("b > 3");
    }
}
if (type == 2) {
    if (b > 3) {
        System.out.println("b > 3");
    } else if (a > 1) {
        System.out.println("a > 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: A switch statement would make it marginally better.

Comment: A switch statement maybe?  It is hard to pick out a pattern in this code that is particularly amenable to refactoring to make it "elegant".  Bear in mind that "elegance" and "optimization" are often antithetical goals.

Comment: are there only ever 2 variables `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Bohemian♦ There are three conditions in the actual project in the if statement, a and b are just for illustration

Comment: How many variables like a and b can there be? Are they all ints?

Comment: @Bohemian♦ The condition may be `list.isEmpty()` or `list.size() > 3`, I use a and b just to express conditions

Comment: In your example the type changes the sequence of the same conditions/actions. Coincidence or something you can work with?

Comment: @Turo No coincidence, the actual logic is like this

Comment: Without seeing the actual code (not something *like* the actual code) it is difficult to give advice on refactoring. It would be like a doctor examining my sister to see if I am healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map<Integer, BiConsumer<Integer, Integer>`.

```
Map<Integer, BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, (a, b) -> {
  if (a > 1) {
      System.out.println("a > 1");
  } else if (b > 3) {
      System.out.println("b > 3");
  }
});
map.put(2, (a, b) -> {
  if (b > 3) {
      System.out.println("b > 3");
  } else if (a > 1) {
      System.out.println("a > 1");
  }
});
```

Then to use:

```
Optional.ofNullable(map.get(type)).ifPresent(c -> c.accept(a, b));
```

Comment: And this is better than the OP’s code because…?

Comment: @Holger because the map can be defined, populated and tested elsewhere from the usage point. The population can even be via spring beans, each condition/lambda pair being its own bean. It’s about decoupling. By using this abstraction, you can alter how, when and where the map is populated, have custom maps for each environment, maintain and upgrade the code, and it’s scaleable. If you bake it in as hard code, you can’t realistically do any of these things.

Comment: Since this motivation hasn’t been stated in the question, shouldn’t it be in your answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a bunch of conditions with associated messages, and want to check them in a different order based on type?

If so, you could declare

```
interface Checker {
    String check();
}
```

and then do:

```
Checker ca = () -> a > 1 ? "a > 1" : null;
Checker cb = () -> b > 3 ? "b > 3" : null;

Checker[][] checkers = {
        null,
        {ca, cb},
        {cb, ca},
};

for (var checker : checkers[type]) {
    var message = checker.check();
    if (message != null) {
        return message;
    }
}
return null;
```

This defines each condition only once, irrespective of how many types there are.

(you could also use a switch expression rather than an array)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a switch statement, it would make it mildly more elegant.
Something along the lines of:

```
        int a = 3, b =  5;
        int type = 2;

        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                if (a>1) System.out.println("a > 1");
                else if (b > 3) System.out.println("b > 3");
                break;
            

            case 2:
                if(b > 3) System.out.println("b > 3");
                else if(a > 1) System.out.println("a > 1");
                break;
        }
```

I hope that was somewhat helpful, good luck!

Comment: Oops, I guess you're right. I was experimenting with C switch statements in the past few days so I got it a little mixed up. Editing, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If check and action are repeating, you could avoid some repetition by sometihng like this.
The bad thing about this is working with sideeffects...

```
private boolean checkA(int a) {

    if (a > 1) {
       System.out.println("a > 1");
       return true;
    } 
    return false;
}

private boolean checkB(int b) {

    if (b > 3) {
       System.out.println("b > 3");
       return true;
    } 
    return false;
}


...

switch (type)
{
     case 1: if (!checkA(a)) {
                  checkB(b);
             }
             break;
     case 2: if (!checkB(b)) {
                  checkA(a);
             }
             break;

}
```

**EDIT**

another nasty way this could be 'abused' is

```
    boolean dummy;
    switch (type)
    {
         case 1: dummy = checkA(a) || checkB(b);
                 break;
         case 2: dummy = checkB(b) || checkA(a);
                 break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start off by using classes for your different types. This will make it easier to add more types with different behaviors. You can then look at simplifying the classes separately. You'll also be able to test them separately with unit tests.

Your example becomes...

```
new Type2(3, 5).process();
```

If you have the following classes

```
public interface Processor {
    void process();
}

public class Type1 implements Processor {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    
    public Type1(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void process() {
        if (a > 1) {
            System.out.println("a > 1");
        } else if (b > 3) {
            System.out.println("b > 3");
        }
    }

}

 public class Type2 implements Processor {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    
    public Type2(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        if (b > 3) {
            System.out.println("b > 3");
        } else if (a > 1) {
            System.out.println("a > 1");
        }
    }

}
```